# websphere port conflict preventing app server from starting

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-6.1

I've tried doing a netstat and the port says it's listening.  Looking at the websphere config files, I couldn't find anything else using this port.  There are no other application servers or non-websphere-related apps using this port.  I've highlighted the problem below in the log.  Any help would be appreciated.

update:  To resolve the issue, we tried moving the port several times by at least a thousand ports.  We've edited the serverindex.xml and everything looks fine.  this isn't a DNS problem either, as the hostname resolves OK from the system.

This is websphere 6.1 express running on an as400.

```
[6/21/11 10:08:25:199 EEST] 0000000a ThreadPoolMgr W   WSVR0626W: The ThreadPool setting on the ObjectRequestBroker service is deprecated.<br>
[6/21/11 10:08:25:264 EEST] 0000000a SSLComponentI I   CWPKI0003I: SSL service is starting<br> 
[6/21/11 10:08:25:281 EEST] 0000000a SSLComponentI I   CWPKI0004I: SSL service started successfully<br>
[6/21/11 10:08:27:944 EEST] 0000000a CoordinatorIm I   HMGR0206I: The Coordinator is an Active Coordinator for core group DefaultCoreGroup. The active coordinator set is [TEST595_ITMUIAppS\TEST595_ITMUIAppS\ITMUIAppS].<br>
[6/21/11 10:08:28:130 EEST] 0000000a DCSPluginSing I   HMGR0005I: The Single Server DCS Core Stack transport has been started for core group DefaultCoreGroup.<br>
[6/21/11 10:08:28:465 EEST] 0000000a ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl initialize FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file /QIBM/UserData/WebSphere/AppServer/V61/Express/profiles/ITMUIAppS/logs/ffdc/ITMUIAppS_0000000a_11.06.21_10.08.28_0.txt<br>
[6/21/11 10:08:28:573 EEST] 0000000a ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file /QIBM/UserData/WebSphere/AppServer/V61/Express/profiles/ITMUIAppS/logs/ffdc/ITMUIAppS_0000000a_11.06.21_10.08.28_0.txt<br>
[6/21/11 10:08:28:592 EEST] 0000000a ORBRas        E **com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport createServerSocket Thread-0 ORBX0390E: Cannot create listener thread. Exception=[ java.net.BindException: Address already in use. - received while attempting to open server socket on port 10038 ].**<br>
[6/21/11 10:08:28:653 EEST] 0000000a ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl open FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file /QIBM/UserData/WebSphere/AppServer/V61/Express/profiles/ITMUIAppS/logs/ffdc/ITMUIAppS_0000000a_11.06.21_10.08.28_1.txt<br>
[6/21/11 10:08:28:720 EEST] 0000000a ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file /QIBM/UserData/WebSphere/AppServer/V61/Express/profiles/ITMUIAppS/logs/ffdc/ITMUIAppS_0000000a_11.06.21_10.08.28_1.txt<br>
[6/21/11 10:08:28:789 EEST] 0000000a ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl open FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file /QIBM/UserData/WebSphere/AppServer/V61/Express/profiles/ITMUIAppS/logs/ffdc/ITMUIAppS_0000000a_11.06.21_10.08.28_2.txt<br>
```

Comment: Have you gone throught this process: Call netstat, then option 3 to view opened ports, option 8 for the job using the port?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the WebSphere listener process is still active from a previous startup. List the java processes using ps (UNIX) or task manager (Win) and kill the one that looks like a WebSphere process. There are also tools for different flavours of UNIX (lsof) and Windows (SysInternals TcpView) that can find the process keeping a TCP port open.

Comment: Or just restart you computer and then try to start the server again.

Comment: We've tried restarting the entire subsystem, with no luck.  This would have eliminated any previous websphere listener processes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who contributed to solve the problem.  We fixed it by setting the port to 0 for the bootstrap server (which lets WAS choose the port).

Comment: Were you able to find the job that is using the port?

Answer (score 0):

Wait you sure it is port conflict on your server and that it's not a connectivity issue from client to server? Firewall?

Looks like you're also registering SSL - your application may be having trouble trying to bind port to the SSL certificates. Have a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791(v=vs.110).aspx

I ran into similar problem before where my web application won't start because it went straight to STEP 3 below (trying to add a binding before deleting existing first)
**STEP 1.** To check existing binding

```
netsh http show sslcert
```

**STEP 2.** To delete a binding before adding it

```
Netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8005
```

**STEP 3.** To add binding

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```